# One Synchronized block compared to multiple AtomicInteger increments

Tags: java, synchronized, volatile, compare-and-swap

I do understand that it is better to use [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead of [synchronized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) block to increment a shared **int** value. However, would it still hold in case of **multiple int** values?

Which one of the below methods would be better and why? Is there a better way to do it to improve performance?

**1) Using synchronized block:**

```
int i, j, k, l;
public void synchronized incrementValues() {
    i++;j++;k++;l++;
}
```

**2) Using AtomicInteger:**

```
AtomicInteger i,j,k,l;
// Initialize i, j, k, l

public void incrementValues() {
    i.incrementAndGet();
    j.incrementAndGet();
    k.incrementAndGet();
    l.incrementAndGet();
}
```

Or would it be faster if I use [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)?

**3) Using ReentrantLock :**

```
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock()
int i, j, k, l;
public void incrementValues() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        i++;j++;k++;l++;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is 3 the fastest of them all?
2. What about 2? For single integer 2 is faster than 1. Will 2 become slower than 1 if the number of integers increase?

**Edit 1**
*Modified question Based on Matthias answer.*

i,j,k,l are independent of each other. Individual increments should be atomic, not the whole. It is ok if thread 2 modifies i before thread 1 modifies k.

**Edit 2**
*Additional Info based on comments so far*

I am not looking for an exact answer, as I understand that it would depend on how the functions are used and the amount of contention etc. and measuring for each of the use cases is the best way to determine the exact answer. However, I would like to see people share their knowledge/articles etc. that would throw light on the parameters/optimizations affecting the situation. Thanks for the article @Marco13. It was informative.

Comment: `AtomicIntegerArray` might also be good. I guess I would go with `synchronized` as it's the simplest, and probably even the best in this case.

Comment: If you really care about perforamce, measure.  If you can't measure enough difference to matter, use the simplest.

Comment: For sure an interesting question, but hard to answer. One would have to run detailed performance tests, e.g. with JMH, and compare the results when applied to 4 variables (as in your case) to the results when using 1...n variables (where "n" may be the point when the `synchronized` becomes faster) - and even then, you could hardly know whether things like lock elision or coarsening ( http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp10185/index.html ) distorted the results to become meaningless...

Comment: Updated my below answer to your new questions

Answer (score 2):

First of all, #2 is not thread safe. incrementAndGet() is atomic, however, calling four incrementAndGet operations in a row is not. (e.g. after the second incrementAndGet, another thread could get into the same method and start doing the same like in the example below.

```
T1: i.incrementAndGet();
T1: j.incrementAndGet();
T1: k.incrementAndGet();
T2: i.incrementAndGet();
T2: j.incrementAndGet();
T1: l.incrementAndGet();
T2: k.incrementAndGet();
T2: l.incrementAndGet();
```

then, if it is between #1 and #3: If you're not into high speed stock trading, it won't matter for you. There might be really small differences (in the case of just integers probably in nanoseconds), but it won't really matter. However, I would always go for #1, as it's much simpler and also much safer to use (e.g. imagine you would have forgotten to put the unlock() in the finally block - then you could get into big trouble)

Regarding your edits:
For number 1: sometimes it could be important to atomically modify several values at once. Consider that data is not only incremented but also read at the same time. You would assume that at any point in time all variables very the same value. However as the update operation is not atomic when you read the data, it could be that I=j=k=5 and l=4 because the thread that did the increment has not yet arrived at the last operation.
Whether this is a problem depends very much on your problem. If you don't need such a guarantee, don't care.

For number 2: 
Optimisation is hard and concurrency is even harder. I can only recommend NOT thinking about such micro  oprimizations. In the best case these optimizations save nanoseconds but make the code very complex. In the worst case there's a false assumption or logical error in the optimisation and you will end up with concurrency problems. Most likely however your optimization will perform worse. 
Also consider that the code you write will probalbly need to be maintained by someone else at a later point in time. And where you saved milliseconds in programming execution you waste hours of you processors life who is trying to understand what you want to do and why you do it this way while attempting to fix that nasty multi threading bug.
So for the sake of ease: synchronized is the best thing to use.

The kiss principle REALLY holds true for concurrency.